# How to place figures side by side in latex and their captions as a and b, with another common caption as figure 1...?

Tags: numbering, captions, subcaption, journal

I'm following International Journal of Computational Methods (IJCM) format.
`subfigure`, `subfloat`, `subcaption` are not working here since this journal template uses older incompatible formats like `\psfig` etc.
If `subfigure`, `subfloat`, `subcaption` etc. are used, the font size etc. are changing.

`minipage` I tried, the caption for the figures placed at that time are getting as fig.1 and fig.2 (I have to get them as a and b), with the common caption fig.3 which I have to obtain as fig.1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a small complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows your setup (class, loaded packages, settings, ...). The answer two your question depends on such 'details'. Click on the `Edit` button left below your posting, paste the code into your question and mark it as code (use the `{}` button).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem.  From your description only can be concluded that you doing something wrong. In minipages you need to redefine caption, if I understand your problem well.

Comment: Is the class file `ijcm.cls` (or whatever it's called) available online?

Comment: `\psfig` (really!!) is an alternative to `\includegraphics` but there is no reason to expect it to affect any caption processing, so without an example it is hard to guess how to answer.

Comment: A solution without package conflicts is  just type "(a)" and "(b)" centered under the images in the minipage.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, just use a `tabular` with the numbering manually inserted; this is a fairly good solution as there's no mention of the subfigure numbering to have the main figure number included.

The example below was taken from the [`ws-ijcm` class source](https://www.worldscientific.com/page/ijcm/stylefiles-readme-2e):

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[th]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c @{\quad} c }
    \includegraphics[width=10em]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[width=10em]{example-image-b} \\
    \small (a) &
      \small (b)
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace*{8pt}
  \caption{A schematic illustration of dissociative recombination. The
  direct mechanism, 4m$^2_\pi$ is initiated when the molecular ion
  S$_{\mathrm{L}}$ captures an electron with kinetic energy.\label{one}}
\end{figure}
```

Referencing the main figure would use the regular `Fig.~\ref{one}` approach, while subfigures can be referenced in a similar way: `Fig.~\ref{one}(a)` (for example).